# Convert Wordpress.com Hosted Blog to BlogEngine.NET

Tags: wordpress, migration, blogengine.net, wordpress.com

I'm looking at what is needed to move from wordpress.com to a BlogEngine.NET or similar blog. I've seen a tool for replacing export.php so that it will export your wordpress site in BlogML format so it can easily be imported into BlogEngine.NET, however I'd really not want to have to setup php/wordpress just so I can import a back up from wordpress.com and then use the export from my local wordpress to have a BlogML file.

Are there any tools that will convert the wordpress file? Is there a different blog that will natively import the wordpress file?

**Edit:** For the question about other blog providers, I am open to them as long as they are .NET based, preferably C#.

Comment: I've been found this, hope this helps to you. http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/07/20/migrate-from-wordpress-to-blogengine-net.aspx See yaa.

Comment: I had saw that earlier, however you need to own your wordpress to use that. Theoretically I could always install wordpress on my computer, import my blog posts back in, then follow that to export it. But that's alot of configuration to use just convert that output.

Comment: What!?!  Only 50 points out of 100???

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the switch to BE.net? I've begun looking at it and it definitely appears to be the best OS .net option (only option?) but still feels immature compared to WP.

Comment: Because we're a .NET shop and I don't want to deal with integrating any other language other than C#/ASP.NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Are there any tools that will convert the wordpress file?*

wordpress.com exports in XML, so that might be easier than using feeds or otherwise grabbing html and parsing it. [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) supports XML into PHPMyAdmin, which exports SQL.

*Is there a different blog that will natively import the wordpress file?*

Are you open to using platforms other than BlogEngine?

Comment: Hadn't thought about the XML.  That may make it easier to convert to the BlogEngine format.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any tool but you may be able to parse the content.  Sort of a fun experiment ;)

The url for the Archives is:  yourblog.wordpress.com/year/month; e.g. yourblog.wordpress.com/2009/11.  The content for the page is wrapped in a div with the id="content".  Each post is wrapped in a child div that contains a class called "post", and the target href is contained in a child H2 tag.

It looks roughly like this:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="post-597 post hentry category-activeengine category-coaching tag-philosophy">
    <h2>
      <a title="Permalink for : More than .Net, jQuery, S3 and Corporate-Speak" href="http://activeengine.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/more-than-net-jquery-s3-and-corporate-speak/">More than .Net, jQuery, S3 and Corporate-Speak</a>
      <em>November 24, 2009</em>
    </h2>
    <em class="info"></em>
  <div class="snap_preview">
</div>
</div>
<div class="post-562 post hentry category-net category-activeengine category-linux category-mono category-new-techniques category-open-source tag-c tag-mono tag-monodevelop">
```

Potentially you could do a get for each monthly archive page and use jQuery to parse out the href to each post.  Once you have all the hrefs you could run another process that would pull down each html file.  You would also need a process for the images.  To keep things easy you could create folder structure that mirrors the archives.

Comment: the markup differs widely depending on the theme used, but there is a feed available for each category, month etc - why not parse that if you have to parse something?

Comment: +1 - didn't think of that.  Basically I opened Firebug and started looking at the tags.  I like your idea as it eliminates the first screen scraping run.