# export from wordpress to blogml

Tags: wordpress, blogml

I would like to export my blog from wordpress to BlogML. I would like to try moving my blog to BlogML based [Blogengine.net](http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/).

I searched around and found this, [wordpress blogML export tool](http://www.nayyeri.net/blog/wordpress-blogml-export/). I tried to use it but I could not complete the export successfully. The export always threw an exception and ended abruptly. I am not sure what caused this.

Is there any tool/method by which I can export wordpress to BlogML?

I am not sure about this but, while searching for this I also read that wordpress does not provide an option to move the blog in a SEO friendly way. Is this correct?

Comment: Doesn't really seem programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dup and answer here: [Convert Wordpress.com Hosted Blog to BlogEngine.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567399/convert-wordpress-com-hosted-blog-to-blogengine-net/1805077)